# Is there a react date picker that allows two week view?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for react date picker that allows for two week view. As shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [react day picker](https://react-day-picker.js.org/) by adding custom range to modifiers object and adding css class to this range.

```
// ...
  const modifiers = {
    hideDays: {
      before: hideBefore,
      after: hideAfter,
    },
  }

  const modifiersStyles = {
    hideDays: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  } 

// ...

<DayPicker
  modifiers={modifiers}
  modifiersStyles={modifiersStyles}
/>
```